# How to slow down the rotation speed for circle-progressbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progress-bar

This question has been asked before, but it does not have any good answers. I know how to speed it up by changing android:toDegrees "" as in this link: http://codebin.co.uk/blog/custom-indeterminate-progressbar-on-android/

If android:toDegrees=" " is set to 360, it spins perfectly one turn in 4 seconds. If android:toDegrees=" " is set to 720, it spins perfectly one turn in 2 seconds.

My problem is if I set android:toDegrees=" " to 180, trying to spin one turn for 8 seconds, it spins half a turn in 4 seconds, and then jumps back to start.

As others have said before, changing android:durtation has no effect on the circle progressbar.
Drawable xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
           <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#EF9A9A"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
<rotate
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="180">
<shape
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <gradient android:color="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#D50000"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false"/>
</shape>
</rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: by increasing the value of toDegrees property